# How to feed messages coming into Apache Apollo from clients into Java?

Tags: jms, message, apollo

Do I use something called the JMS (Java Messaging Service)? Basically I need to collate all messages sent out by the client to the message bus in such a format that is friendly with Java in order to carry out some back-end tasks with those messages.

Answer (score 0):

You will need keep the below in mind before choosing an interface:

1) Type of interface your messaging bus supports for client applications to connect. If JMS is the only interface available, then no choice for you.

2) If it provides proprietary Java interface and you have no plans to switch other messaging bus, then you can choose proprietary interface.

3) If the messages that you collect need to be transported other application and if that application understands only JMS messages.

4) Developer skills on Java/JMS.

Comment: I can feed it into a SQLite Db and then use the db with Java. Is that a good way to go about it?

Comment: Apollo itself provides Java client API

Comment: Why don't you use the Apollo Java client to collate messages?